# Memory Error when numpy.dot(A,B), where A is 250000x108 float matrix, B is transpose of A

Tags: memory, numpy, dot-product

Any idea of do A dot B, without Memroy Error?

Comment: Memory Error when numpy.dot(A,B), where A is 250000x108 float matrix, B is transpose of A.

Comment: I need that 250000x250000 matrix, dont know how to do it in this case, large scale data.

Comment: Are the arrays at least somewhat sparse? (i.e. do they contain a lot of zeros?)

Comment: Then use a sparse matrix library like `scipy.sparse`. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html  `numpy`, by itself, doesn't include sparse matrices. They're in `scipy.sparse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result would be a 250000x250000 matrix, and would require about half a terabyte of RAM.

Did you mean `numpy.dot(B, A)`?

Comment: I need that 250000x250000 matrix, dont know how to do it in this case, large scale data.

Answer (score 0):

The dot product you are trying to calculate produces a 250000x250000 array, which will require **500Gb** of memory if you are using the default double precision floating point. Are you sure that is what you need?